# Let $H=\{[0]_8, [4]_8\} \subset \Bbb Z_8$ and $[a]_8 \sim [b]_8$ if $-[a]_8 +[b]_8 \in H$. Determine the elements in the equivalence class of $[1]_8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

> Let $H=\{[0]_8, [4]_8\}$ be a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_8$ and let $[a]_8 \sim [b]_8$ if $-[a]_8 +[b]_8 \in H$. Determine the elements in the equivalence class of $[1]_8$.

I’m slightly confused about how I can find the elements of the equivalence class of $[1]_8$. The elements of $[1]_8$ are the cosets $1+8\Bbb Z$ so $[1]_8 = \{..., -9,...,1,...9,... \}$ so am I supposed to use these elements to determine the equivalence classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** It helps to sound out what it is saying: "The elements of the $\sim$-equivalence class of $[1]_8$ are precisely those elements of $\Bbb Z_8$ that differ from $[1]_8$ by an element of $H$."

> The equivalence class is $$\{[1]_8, [5]_8\}.$$

Comment: Not sure I follow. Is addition or subtraction defined on equivalence classes? I.e is $-[a]_8 + [b]_8 = -[a+b]_8$?

Comment: Here subtraction, @Wondera, is defined via addition of an additive inverse: $$\begin{align} -[a]_8+[b]_8&=[-a]_8+[b]_8 \\ &=[(-a)+b]_8\\ &=[b-a]_8.\end{align}$$

Comment: I still don’t see how I can get the equivalence classes of $[1]_8$ There is no such $-[a]_8 + [b]_8 \in H$ that would form $[1]_8$? The closest I have is that $[1]_8 = [4-3]_8 = -[4]_8 + [3]_8$, where $[4]_8 \in H$, but $[3]_8$ isn’t.

Comment: But $$[4-3]_8\neq -[4]_8+[3]_8,$$ @Wondera.

Comment: **Hint:** Set either $a$ or $b$ equal to $1$, @Wondera.

Comment: Also, there is only one equivalence class of $[x]_8$ for any $x$, @Wondera.

Comment: If $a=1$, then $-[1]_8 + [b]_+ = [b-1]_8 = (b-1) + 8\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, @Wondera, but then, also, $[b-1]_8\in H$.

Comment: Also if $b = 1$, then $-[a]_8 + [1]_8 = [1-a]_8$ so the equivalence classes of $[1]_8$ are $[b-1]_8$ and $[1-a]_8$?

Comment: You can figure out what those $a$ and $b$ can be since both $[1-a]_8$ and $[b-1]_8$ are in $H$, @Wondera.

Comment: I've added a spoiler, @Wondera.